# Entityframework generic way to access entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics

is there a way to make this generic

```
Context.SalesEntity.Where(t=>t.id==3).Delete();
```

something like

```
private void DoWork<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
{
  Context.T.Where(predicate).Delete();
}
```

I have already tried the predicate bit seems to work ok. but I have no idea how to do the context.entity bit generically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private void DoWork<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
{
  Context.Set<T>().Where(predicate).Delete();
}
```

Comment: List<int> deleteIds...

int rowsEffected = Context.Set<T>()
      .Where(t => deleteIds.Contains(???)).Delete();

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `Context.Set<T>` method. This returns a `DbSet<T>` of the specified type.